# ASP.NET Web application cannot identify UNC folder

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-7

Having a bit of trouble after migrated my app to IIS 7. Everything was working perfectly when it runs under IIS6.

The main problem is I have a UNC mapped folder (Folder A) under the root folder of the my web application. This folder is located in same network but in different server.

So when I try to access this from my ASP.NET site, instead of reading the contents from the remote UNC path, my application looking for FolderA in Web Server which it clearly fails.

The application runs as a custom user which has pretty much all permissions it needs

I'm running out of ideas here and can anyone shed some lights please?